# MariaDB: subselect in COALESCE throws ERROR 1064 (42000)

Tags: sql, mariadb

**Intention**: I want to subselect values within a `coalesce` function in MariaDB (10.7.1).

**Problem**:
Executing this SQL statement ...

```
select coalesce(select id from MY_TABLE limit 1);
```

... throws this error message:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'select id from MY_TABLE limit 1)' at line 1
```

**Workarounds / checks I tried**:

- `select id from MY_TABLE limit 1;` returns a valid value. So that part of the statement is fine.
- `select coalesce('a');` returns the value `a`. So executing `coalesce` with one parameter only is also fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must make the result of `select` to be an expression. Statement is not an expression

```
with MY_TABLE as (
      select 1 as id
     )
select coalesce((select id from MY_TABLE limit 1)) c;
```

Note the result of LIMIT without ORDER BY is an arbitrary row.

Comment: Thank you! Adding an additional pair of brackets was the trick. :-)

Comment: Yes, you are right: LIMIT without ORDER BY is arbitrary. I wanted to keep the example short.

Answer (score 0):

The `COALESCE` function typically takes 2 or more arguments.  The value returned is the first value which is *not* `NULL`.  You probably intend something like this:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(id, 'missing') AS id
FROM MY_TABLE
ORDER BY <some column>
LIMIT 1;
```